# Iterating and using switch case with this response

Tags: javascript

I am using the for loop to iterate my response, but now i need a switch case inside to decide based on _type... and send it to different functions...

Comment: Where's the real, specific question?

Comment: @RobW: I want to iterate the response and then use Switch case to decide based on type and send Allergy to specific function... similarly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
var PAST_SURGICAL_HISTORY_SECTION, 
    ALLERGY_SECTION = 
    'PastSurgicalHistorySection', 
    'AllergySection';

length = json.PatientFaceSheetGetResult.FaceSheetItems.length;
for (i = 0, i < length; i++)  {
     var result = json.PatientFaceSheetGetResult.FaceSheetItems[i];
     var type = result['__type'].split(':')[0];

     switch(type) {
         case PAST_SURGICAL_HISTORY_SECTION:
             break;
         case ALLERGY_SECTION:
             break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Dupanovic: Should i use var type = result['__type'].split(':')[i]; like this or zero what does Zero correspond there

Comment: Split will return a tuple of the contents left and right of the `:` delimiter. `0` just means you want the left part when you split, say `AllergySection:#Greenway.PrimeSuite.DataContracts.Person.Patient.FaceSheets` by `:`, which would be `AllergySection`.